# ASP.NET WebForms Unable to call webmethod from javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I can't seem to get this simple function working.

The AJAX call returns success but the function is never being called since the `Debug.WriteLine` is not showing up. The "Function has been called" alert *does* pop up. There are no errors in the Chrome console.

I am using ASP.NET Web Forms

The Contact.aspx.cs file:

```
public partial class Contact : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Contact Page loaded");
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Test(string test)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Input param"+test);
        return test;
    }  
}
```

In the Contact.aspx file

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="ShowTest()">Test</button>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    function ShowTest() {            

        //Tried this also (prefered)
        //var res = PageMethods.Test("testMessage");

        var testMsg = 'This is the test message';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Contact.aspx/Test",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                test: testMsg
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                alert('It worked! ' + result.d);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('Nope');
            }
        });

        alert("Function has been called");
    }       
</script>
```

Comment: What is in `result` in the success function?  Out of curiosity, where are you looking for the `Debug.WriteLine` output?

Comment: Hi David. The result shows undefined.

Comment: The output is showing in visual studio console. I do get the "Contact Page loaded" showing up.

Comment: Is what I am doing the standard way of calling C# code from web page? Are there better ways then ajax?

Comment: No, this should be pretty standard.  Though I may be missing something obvious, I haven't done WebForms in a very long time.  In your browser's debugging tools, what's the server's response to the AJAX call?

Comment: The alert "result.d" shows "It Worked! undefined". Is there another way of debugging this?

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, check the network tab and see the requests/responses.

Comment: Wow, we have a lead: {Message: "Authentication failed.", StackTrace: null,…}
ExceptionType
:
"System.InvalidOperationException"
Message
:
"Authentication failed."
StackTrace
:
null

Comment: Afraid I can't help much with that, but at least it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication failed in call webmethod from jquery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014866/authentication-failed-in-call-webmethod-from-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution!

[Authentication failed in call webmethod from jquery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014866/authentication-failed-in-call-webmethod-from-jquery-ajax)

> Blockquote

I found the answer

Just comment below line in RouteConfig file

//settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;

Comment: I don't know what it's for but at this point I am just happy it's working. What a dreadful bug.