# jquery ajax loads page instead of asp.net web method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a jQuery AJAX call that sends form object to the server.Actually i want to send the file object for this   iam using html input file and a input submit button.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
   <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="Submit"  />
 <form>
```

Here is my submit click

```
  $('#Button1').click(function (event) {
   $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "Test.aspx/ag",
                      data: {},
                      processData: false,
                      contentType: false,                                
                      success: function (data) {
                          alert(data);
                      }
 });

 });
```

The code behind is following

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]  
    public static int ag()  
    {  
       HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["myFile"];  
    }
```

The Webmethod is no longer being fired though, instead the Page_load of the page which the webmethod is on is  being fired. Why?  What can I do? In server side i want to get the file.I am using framework 4.0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865557/page-load-is-fired-instead-of-web-method

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but issue is not solved

Answer (score 0):

This is happening beacause you are using a "Submit" button which means that form will be submitted whole you need to change it's type from Submit to "button".

Comment: I'm not using a submit button and I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your Site.Master, in the asp:ScriptManager element, make sure that it includes a EnablePageMethods="true" attribute